# Mixed RAM apparently leads to garbled output on a Dell Vostro 3800 running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: memory, ubuntu-14.04, dell-vostro

I have a [Dell Vostro 3800](http://www.dell.com/in/business/p/vostro-3800-slim-tower/pd) running Ubuntu 14.04. It’s memory capacity is 16GB. Recently it was running with two 4GB RAM sticks and working fine. When I added an 8GB RAM stick by removing one of the two 4GB RAM sticks and then restarted it would sometimes gives me garbled output and then shutdown without notice.

Is the solution to have two 4GB RAM sticks together or 8GB RAM sticks together and that mixing is not permitted due to some voltage restrictions?

This is the output of

```
dmidecode --type memory
```

and it shows that the DDR3 clock speed is 1600 Mhz. The other 8 GB memory card has clock speed of 1800 Mhz. I presume the different clock speeds are the cause of the malfunction. If I get a RAM chip with same clock speed will they work ?

```
# dmidecode 3.0
 Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
 SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0010
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: Unknown
Data Width: Unknown
Size: No Module Installed
Form Factor: DIMM
Set: None
Locator: DIMM1
Bank Locator: Not Specified
Type: Unknown
Type Detail: None
Speed: Unknown
Manufacturer: [Empty]
Serial Number: [Empty]
Asset Tag: 9876543210
Part Number: [Empty]
Rank: Unknown
Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0010
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 8192 MB
Form Factor: DIMM
Set: None
Locator: DIMM2
Bank Locator: Not Specified
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: 1600 MHz
Manufacturer: 1315
Serial Number: 22181710
Asset Tag: 9876543210
Part Number: ZION8GBDDR3PC1600 
Rank: 2
Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
```

Comment: garbled how? A screenshot or photo may be illuminating

Comment: Does the 8GB module work okay by itself?  I.E. is it suitable for the motherboard?

Comment: Use a camera. I've had a situation where a video card was messed up an there's a certain, fairly unique way it would glitch.

Comment: The memory timings of the chips are incompatible.  You need to go into the bios and hope your bios is not dumbed down and allows you to adjust the memory timings.  Use **cpuid** and the SPD tab to identify valid settings for you old memory and lookup or refer to the packaging for the memory settings on the new ram.  The highest setting wins.  If you have CAS 3 and 4 you must use 4. Except for Mhz there the lowest one wins. (so 1866 vs 1333 the 1333 wins.

Comment: @gansub if they have the same timings